# Problema con animaciones en ViewPager(Fragmentos) - Lottie

Tags: android

Buenas tardes.

Tengo un viewPager con 5 fragmentos, cada fragmento tiene en su layout un "LottieAnimationView" del la libreria Lottie que se está usando para reproducir las animaciones, el funcionamiento de estas animaciones es correcta, cuando el usuario entra a la actividad que posee las animaciones y NO TOCA la pantalla las animaciones se reproducirán automáticamente y pasará al siguiente fragmento a reproducir la siguiente animación, así sucesivamente hasta llegar al último; en el caso de que el usuario toque la pantalla la animación que se esté reproduciendo lo hará normalmente pero ya no pasará al siguiente fragmento, esta implementación está hecha correctamente.

**El problema que tengo es que cuando el usuario ha tocado la pantalla y la animación que se está reproduciendo termina, no logro que se reinicie(la animación), solo logro que se repita la primera animación mas no las demás.**

*Esta es mi actividad principal:*

```
public class TutorialActivity extends BaseActivity implements 
  Tuto1Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, 
  Tuto2Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, 
  Tuto3Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, 
  Tuto4Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, 
  Tuto5Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, 

PromoTutoFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
private MyPagerAdapter mFragmentAdapter;
public ViewPager mViewPager;

// Sirve para determinar los inicios de las animaciones en cada Fragment
public static boolean noPasar = false;
// Sirve para detener la animación del ViewPager cuando pulsas sobre un tab
public static boolean stopPager = true;

//List<Offer> previewOffers;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial);
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    // Añadir el adapter al ViewPager
    mFragmentAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mFragmentAdapter);
    // Cargar los 5 fragment depués de iniciar la actividad
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
    // Añadir touch cuando el usuario cambie manualmente los fragment
    mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            //Variable en false cuando el usuario ha tocado la pantalla
            TutorialActivity.stopPager = false;

            return false;
        }
    });

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager, true);
    // Buscar los tab generados en el TabLayout
    LinearLayout tabStrip = (LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    // Añadir el evento click sobre los tabs
    for (int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TutorialActivity.stopPager = false;
            }
        });
    }
    // Añadir el evento cambio de Fragment a los tabs sin efecto de traslado
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(), false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

    });

    // Iniciar en el 1° Fragment y no iniciar transición
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);

}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Tuto1Fragment();
            case 1:
                return new Tuto2Fragment();
            case 2:
                return new Tuto3Fragment();
            case 3:
                return new Tuto4Fragment();
            case 4:
                return new Tuto5Fragment();
                /*if (previewOffers != null)
                    return PromoTutoFragment.newInstance(previewOffers.get(0));
                else return new PromoTutoFragment();*/
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

   }
 }
```

*Este es mi fragmento 1:*

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tuto1, container, false);
    animationView = view.findViewById(R.id.animation);
    animationView.addAnimatorListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            //Log.e("AnimaS", "tuto1");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(final Animator animation) {
            //Log.e("AnimaE", "tuto1");
            try {
                // Solo realizará el cambio de Fragment si la variable es true
                if (TutorialActivity.stopPager){
                    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                            new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    if (getActivity() != null)
                                        ((TutorialActivity) getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
                                }
                            },
                            300);
                }else{
                    //Si es false se reproducirá la misma animación
                    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                            new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    if (getActivity() != null){
                                        ((TutorialActivity) getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
                                        animation.start();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            300);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //Para capturar cuando no esta listo para cambiar
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Para los otros fragmentos es el mismo código, **la primera animación se repite correctamente, pero a partir de la 2 ya no**, la animación se malogra(se pasa a la primera luego a la segunda, se pone un poco loco las animaciones), la única parte que cambio es:

```
      if (TutorialActivity.stopPager){
                    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                            new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    if (getActivity() != null)
                                        ((TutorialActivity) getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2, false);
                                }
                            },
                            300);
                }else{
                    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                            new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    if (getActivity() != null){
                                        ((TutorialActivity) getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
                                        animation.start();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            300);
                }
```

Comment: No se si he entendido bien, te refieres a que si el usuario cambia de fragment manualmente, el siguiente fragment ya tiene la animación empezada?

Comment: Me refiero a que si el usuario comienza a manipular las animaciones, la animación que esté corriendo en ese instante deba repetirse al terminar; logré hacerlo con la primera animación(fragmento 1) pero con las demás no.